# Php Function that outputs an Array Result

Tags: php

I am trying to return an array through my function but get an array error when i try to print the result. It just shows "Array". Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
function selectHtmlSelectBox($selectHtmlSelectBox_option, $dbConnection)
{
$selectHtmlSelectBox_option=sanitizeInt($selectHtmlSelectBox_option, $dbConnection);

    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[1]=='';
    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[2]=='';
    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[3]=='';

    if($selectHtmlSelectBox_option=='1')
    {
    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[1]='selected';
    }
    elseif($selectHtmlSelectBox_option=='2')
    {
    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[2]='selected';
    }
    elseif($selectHtmlSelectBox_option=='3')
    {
    $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return[3]='selected';
    }

    return $selectHtmlSelectBox_option_return;
}


$a[]=selectHtmlSelectBox('2', $dbConnection);
echo $a[0];
echo $a[1];
echo $a[2];
echo $a[3];
```

Comment: It shows "Array" cause you cannot `echo` an array, you should print it like `print_r($a);` And if `echo $a[0];` shows "Array",  it's probably because `echo $a[0];` contains an (empty) array as well.

Comment: You're assigning to `$a[]`... wut? I think you just want to assign to `$a`, then `$a[1]` will be a useful operation.

Comment: Also: please use shorter variable names, and use spaces. That simple piece of code is *really* unnecessarily straining on the eyes.

Comment: `$a=selectHtmlSelectBox('2', $dbConnection);`

Answer (score 0):

I had to removed the [] brackets.

```
$a=selectHtmlSelectBox('2', $dbConnection);
echo $a[0];
echo $a[1];
echo $a[2];
echo $a[3];
```